# rewriting sql command that uses IN

Tags: sql

I have three tables:

```
Product(maker, model, type)
PC(model, speed, ram, hd, price)
Laptop(model, speed, ram, hd, screen, price)
```

And I'm trying to find the makers that sell Laptops but not PC's. I think I have achieved this with the following command:

```
select product.maker
from product
where product.maker not in 
    (select maker
    from pc, product
    where product.model = pc.model)
and product.maker in 
    (select maker
    from laptop, product
    where product.model = laptop.model);
```

However I want to rewrite this without using IN and NOT IN.

Comment: Hint: Use `EXISTS(...)` and `NOT EXISTS(...)`

Comment: @wildplasser I mean not using exists either, I should have said so. I'm looking for a way to rewrite using only the "basic" operators.

Comment: IMHO `EXISTS(...)` is **very** basic. And it is older than the ugly `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE NULL` syntax below.

Comment: What is the `type` field?

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to use `not exists` and `not in` you can use `left join ... is null`

```
select distinct p.maker
from product p
join laptop l on l.model = p.model
left join pc on pc.model = p.model
where pc.model is null
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to rewrite this using joins:

```
select distinct p.maker
from product p
left outer join product p1 on p.maker=p1.maker
    inner join pc on p1.model = pc.model 
inner join product p2 on p.maker=p2.maker
    inner join laptop on p2.model = laptop.model
where pc.model is null
```

The `product` is used three times in your query; this query does the same thing. However, since it uses ANSI joins without subqueries, `product` is used with aliases.

Comment: This should return no makers for my db but it returns all of them. I don't think I provided enough information. Product contains only the model numbers for laptops and pc's and their makers and type so it's an aggregate table of sorts.

Comment: @ÞórÓðinsson Consider making a sample on [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/), and updating the question with it. This would let us adjust the query to your requirements, and share the results with you.

Comment: This query is not the same as the original query.  The joins are on the model level, so basically every maker that has a laptop product will have a product that doesn't match the pcs.  Hence, this should return any makes with a laptop product.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do this with `join`s, I would recommend the following approach:

```
select p.maker
from product p left outer join
     pc
     on p.model = pc.model left outer join
     laptop l
     on p.model = l.model
group by p.maker
having sum(case when pc.model is not null then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
       sum(case when l.model is not null then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

The `having` clause could equivalently be expressed as:

```
having max(pc.model) is null and
       max(l.model) is not null;
```

Rewriting this using `not exists` would still require having joins in the subqueries.  I suspect that the `type` field might contain information such as `pc` and `laptop`.  If so, then the easiest way is:

```
select p.maker
from product p
group by p.maker
having sum(case when p.type = 'pc' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
       sum(case when p.type = 'laptop' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Or, alternatively:

```
select distinct pl.maker
from product pl left join
     product pp
     on pp.maker = pl.maker and
        pp.type = 'pc'
where pl.type = 'laptop' and pp.maker is null;
```